# cannot escape quited asterisk "*" when parsing it with curl as post request from jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, shell, jenkins, groovy

I have part of XML config file which is read by another java app. This value is passed for filtering and groovy puts it in the file through the pipeline. The problem is that when groovy tries to parse asterix in double quotes and I can't find a way to escape it.

I tried like \"\*\" and many variations with single and double quotes and expressing it var, then bring it in as value did not work

`curl --location --request POST some.link/api/.../properties --header 'X-Corellation-Id: abcd' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"addOrUpdate": [{ "name": "pod1" , "properties": { "DOMAIN" : "<domain type="*"</" }}]}`

<<What we see after execution: >>>>>

Please correct and post again.

`","reason":"Malformed request body","details":[{"field":null,"messages":["JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('' (code 42)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('*' (code 42))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
script {
        def data = '{"addOrUpdate": [{"name": "pod1","properties": {"DOMAIN": "<domain type=\"*\" </"}}]}'
        writeFile(file: 'data.json', text: data)
        sh "cat data.json"
        sh "curl -v --request POST http://localhost:8080 --header 'X-Corellation-Id: abcd' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @data.json"           
   }
```